# Email logging with Python Django

Tags: python, django, logging

Django does support email log handlers.

But this way, if some error is repeated often, we risk to be mail-bombed by ERROR emails.

How to send us emails on errors but not too often?

Any other solutions?

Comment: I'm not using the django's log handlers but I use getsentry. It does what you want and even more but it is not free.

Comment: @ÇağatayBarın [sentry](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry) is free if you set it up yourself on your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `BufferingSMTPHandler` as described in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/1379446). You can adapt the described class to your needs.